# CSS 3 DIVs in a row : 2 fix 1 auto adjust

Tags: css

I am trying to figure out how to create 3 divs and have them lineup in the same row.
Having 1st and 3rd one fixed width at 100px and have the 2nd (middle) one audo adjust its width in case of browser resize.

```
<div>
   <div id="d1"> content 1</div>
   <div id="d2"> content 2</div>
   <div id="d3"> content 3</div>
</div>
```

thanks,

Comment: I am *itching* to suggest `<table style='width: 100%'><tr><td style='width: 100px'>content 1</td><td>content 2</td><td style='width: 100px'>content 3</td></tr></table>` ... but maybe there's an elegant CSS-based way, too. We'll see.

Comment: There is ... see answers ... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-3-column-holy-grail-pixels.htm</strike>

Strike that, many extra divs to ensure all columns are equal height. [This may be what you're looking for.](http://www.alistapart.com/d/holygrail/example_4.html) All explained in this excellent article: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail

Comment: ugh - why would you do a bunch of CSS hacks w/ negative margins and padding when tables work perfectly? Irresponsible.

Comment: @Wells Because using tables for layout is even more irresponsible. Tables are for tabular data.

Answer (score 5):

You have tp use floats to align the left and right frame. But for this you have to reorder the divs as shown below, and set the margins for the middle div.

```
<style type="text/css">
#d1 {
  float: left;
}

#d2 {
  float: right;
}

#d3 {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
</style>

<div>
   <div id="d1"> content 1</div>
   <div id="d2"> content 2</div>
   <div id="d3"> content 3</div>
</div>
```

**Edit**

Thanks to [Leniel Macaferi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114029/leniel-macaferi) for pointing out an error. The correct order of the `div`s has to be floating `div`s first, then non floating `div`s. Therefore I corrected the code (exchanged `div` d2 and `div` d3).

Comment: @LenielMacaferi thanks for pointing out that there is an error, the corrected code now works ... http://jsbin.com/evagat/1/edit

Answer (score 3):

Div is a block-level element, so its a nice option to handle  with the help of its Display Property.

```
<div id="d1" style="display:inline-block; width:100px;">content1</div>
<div id="d2" style="display:inline">content2</div>
<div id="d3" style="display:inline-block; width:100px;">content3</div>​
```

Answer (score 1):

Just putting this out there as a modern, clean solution: use `calc`.
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bg7KS/

```
#d2 {
    width: 200px; /* fallback older browsers */
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 200px);
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 200px);
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

nvm this is old, i was gonna post what worked for me

```
    <style type="text/css">
#d1 {

  float: left;
  margin-left: 50px;

}

#d2 {
  float: center;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#d3 {
float: left;
 margin-right: 5px;
}
</style>

<div>
   <div id="d1"> content 1</div>
   <div id="d3"> content 3</div>
   <div id="d2"> content 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no value 'center' for float in CSS. (See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)